# How to prevent the user from intercepting the closing animation on a drawer

Tags: android, drawer

The title basically says it all:

In my code i call drawer.closeDrawers();
but when the user pushes a button in the linearlayout from the left drawer
while the closing animation is running, the left drawer reopens again.

I tried to set focusable and clickable false on the linearlayout until the
animation is done, but that doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I figered to just put the drawer into lockmode after calling closedrawers()